# Non vanishing gradient condition in control barrier funcions.

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics, lyapunov-functions, set-invariance

I am reading about barrier functions in control engineering/dynamical systems. These tools are used to prove that the system is forward invariant with respect to a set $\mathcal{C}$ (i.e., starting in $\mathcal{C}$, we stay in $\mathcal{C}$ at all times). The concept is similar to the one of Lyapunov functions for stability. Here is the main idea:

Let the dynamical system be $\dot{x} = f(x)$. For simplicity, $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Let also $\mathcal{C}$ be defined as:

$\mathcal{C} = ${$x \in \mathbb{R}^n: h(x) \geq 0$}

$\partial\mathcal{C} = ${$x \in \mathbb{R}^n: h(x) = 0$}

$\text{Int}({\mathcal{C}}) = ${$x \in \mathbb{R}^n: h(x) < 0$}

Where $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function.

We can see that if $h(x(t)) \geq 0$ for all $t \geq t_0$, then the system is forward invariant with respect to $\mathcal{C}$.

Using Nagumo's theorem (see Theorem 3.1 of [1]), the condition that $h \geq 0$ is fulfilled if

$$
\dot{h} \geq 0 \text{ whenever } h = 0 \qquad \text{(1)}
$$

Clearly this would translate directly to:

$$
\dot{h}(x) \geq 0 \quad \forall x \in \partial \mathcal{C} \qquad \text{(2)}
$$

However, it seems that to make this step you need to impose the condition that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \neq 0$ for $x \in \partial \mathcal{C}$ (see, for instance, the first paragraph in section 1.A of [2]). I do not know where this condition comes from.

I know it makes sense: if $h(x)$ has an inflection point at $\partial \mathcal{C}$, then $\dot{h} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} = 0$, and (1) is fulfilled no matter the value of $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ (even if $x$ is "leaving" the set $\mathcal{C}$). I just don't know how it appeared when going from (1) to (2).

[1] *Blanchini, F.*, [**Set invariance in control**](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0005-1098(99)00113-2), Automatica 35, No. 11, 1747-1767 (1999). [ZBL0935.93005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0935.93005).

[2] *Ames, Aaron D.; Xu, Xiangru; Grizzle, Jessy W.; Tabuada, Paulo*, [**Control barrier function based quadratic programs for safety critical systems**](https://doi.org/10.1109/TAC.2016.2638961), IEEE Trans. Autom. Control 62, No. 8, 3861-3876 (2017). [ZBL1373.90092](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1373.90092).

Comment: Can you provide the quote that makes you think (1) to (2) requires that condition? (1) to (2) is just a substitution of definitions. It doesn't require that condition. If memory serves, it is the conclusion that the state stays in $C$ that requires the non-singularity condition. (i.e. if $\nabla_x h$ is non-singular, then you can say something about the direction of $\dot x$ since $\dot h = \nabla_x h \cdot \dot x$)

Comment: In the reference [2] it says "assuming that the safe set C is the superlevel set of a smooth function $h: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and that $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} \neq 0$ for all $x$ such that $h(x) = 0$, then Nagumo's theorem gives neceary and suficicient conditions for set invariance based upon the derivative of h on the boundary of $\mathcal{C}$: $\mathcal{C}$ is invariant $\iff$ $\dot{h}(x)\geq 0 \qquad \forall x \in \partial C$."

Comment: Actually, I am realizing now that it might have to do with the fact that in the condition (1), it is required that the IVP $\dot{h} = f(h)$ has unique solutions for each initial state. Maybe having $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = 0$ when $h = 0$ implies non-unique solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From (1) to (2) you do not need the non-singularity of $h$. It is straight from definitions that $\dot h \geq 0$ on $\partial C$.

To use Nagumo's Theorem, there is one fact we must establish: that for all points $x\in\partial C$ we have that the vector field $f(x(t))$ lay in what is known as the *tangent cone of $S$ at $x$*. That condition essentially means that $\dot x$ is somehow pointing "into" the set $C$ instead of "out of". The definition is a bit opaque at first, and ideally we would not want to establish that $f(x(t))$ lies in the tangent cone explicitly. So how can side-step this? There is a comment on [pg. 1751, 1] saying,

> If such a boundary [$\partial C$] is smooth in the point $x$, then the [tangent cone] is just the tangent halfspace shifted to the origin.

Blanchini says here that when $\partial C$ is smooth, really all we need to be sure of is that $f(x(t))$ lies on "inner side" of the tangent half-space. How does having a non-singular $dh$ help with this? Well, fixing $x \in \partial C,$ we can use an appropriate level set theorem (see [Corollary 5.14, 3]) to argue that $h$ *defines* $\partial C$ as a regular level set locally and thus conclude that $\partial C$ is a smooth embedded submanifold of the ambient space. That isn't all, however. Notably, being an embedded submanifold ensures there is a slice coordinate chart locally around $x$ where $\partial C$ is flat and $dh$ points orthogonal to the flattened $\partial C$ in the new coordinate system. That is, there exists a local diffeomorphism $z = \Phi(x)$ on an open set $U$ where,

$$
U \cap \partial C = \{ (z^1, \ldots, z^{n-1}, 0) \colon z \in U\}
$$

where $dh = dz^n$. We can use this to establish that $f$ is inside the tangent cone. Observe that on $\partial C$,

$$
\dot h(x(t)) \geq 0 \iff dh(f) \geq 0
$$

viewing $dh$ as a form and $f$ as a vector field. In the now flattened $\partial C$, $dh = dz^n$, so really we have,

$$
dz^{n}(f) \geq 0
$$

From this, deduce that $f$ lies in the tangent halfspace coinciding with the tangent cone.

The non-singularity of $dh$ is thus used to simplify the evaluation of the tangent cone criterion by saying that $h$ actually defines $\partial C$ as  smooth embedded submanifold and leveraging this easy to evaluate condition for the tangent cone. That is not to say that you couldn't use Nagumo's Theorem without non-singularity, but that you'd have to painstakingly evaluate that tangent cone criterion at those singular points.

[3] J. M. Lee. *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.* 2nd Ed.

Comment: Very interesting answer. I would need to dig into that.